# Sell products in pack with restriction of choice

Tags: product, bundled-product

i want to sell products in packs like table, chair and flower all set to qty 1,

So i made bundled product now issue is that i want that will not have option to remove items from packs , he will have to buy it as set .

How can i do this .

Please not table , chair and flower are simple products .

Comment: suggted only:-http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove bundle selections from the cart individually, you can only reconfigure your bundle. So the only thing you need to do is make the bundle options required.